# Can JavaScript be used to push a file to another machine or web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, push, cross-site

I'm relatively new to this

We have a requirement to save a file with out the use of the dialog box.
I was wondering if I can use AJAX or some other JavaScript to "Push" the file from the client PC being viewed in a browser to to some web service the client is running and have it save the file.

Do I get into cross site scripting issues or an issue I don't know about at present?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use an `input[type=file]`?

Comment: If it were possible for a web-page to access my local file structure with JavaScript, I wouldn't connect to the Internet...

Comment: What, from some random place on the users machine that the user won't select? That'd be a security violation.  If the user does select it, then there are a few methods.

Answer (score 1):

With [valums uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) script, users can drag and drop files (in certain browsers) to a button on the page.. so, yes, no dialog box, but it still requires user interaction.  (I also know IE10 should be able to handle drag/drop functionality from one of their demos; so this kind of functionality is gaining ground).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload a file without a dialog box.  That would remove the user interaction, so it would be the same thing as allowing a webpage to select any file it wanted and upload it without user interaction - an obvious security flaw.

Comment: is it really possible to skip user interaction of selecting a file from his file system ? And that with javascript? (wondering!)

Comment: No, it should not be possible.  It should require some interaction, whether a file picker of some sort, or drag-drop where supported.

Comment: that's what i thought ! As far as javascript is concerned, it can do some amazing things. But something like accessing file system is not in it's purpose of creation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, without a dialog box, no it can't be done.

HTML5 has a file API where the web app can store files on the local machine. But this access to the filesystem is sandboxed, so you get to access files only under your directory.

Why can't you do without a dialog box? Imagine you visit some site and it "uploads" files without your permission. That's a security *FAIL*. The dialog box is the user's authentication for the file to be uploaded.

Comment: Because it is a dumb requirement from our client Sys. Admins who don't want there users to change the save file location.  Other wises this is a trivial task.